# What does the command `set root =` in Grub2?

Tags: grub2

Could someone explain why we should use in Grub2 the command `set root=` ?

Answer (score 2):

It changes the root partition, so the following operations e.g. `linux something` or `initrd something` don't need to specify the full path. You can simply enumerate from the root directory.